# Keep getting a TypeError: data.coordinates is undefined

Tags: html, google-maps, heatmap

[Image of what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSE5i.png) Creating a heatmap but having trouble resolving:

> TypeError: data.coordinates is undefined.

How would I define data.coordinates within this HTML file and where in this code?

```
         $.eventsource({
            label: "json-event-source",
            url: "http://localhost:5000/tweets?callback=loomit",
            dataType: "json",
          open: function() {
            console.log( "opened" );
        },

        message: function( data ) {
            console.log(  data.coordinates.coordinates );
            heatmap.addDataPoint(data.coordinates.coordinates[1], data.coordinates.coordinates[0]); //this is where I believe there's an issue
        }
```

Should display a heatmap using the Google Maps API

Comment: What does your JSON look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I attached an image above with the issue I'm experiencing. The code above is what the TypeError is referencing.

Comment: Does your JSON actually contain an object key named "coordinates"? Please share a sample of what "data" contains and your code so that we can reproduce this issue from our side and be able to help. Note that a heatmap can render either LatLng or WeightedLocation objects and they must be passed to the heatmap as an array. I highly recommend you follow [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer#add-a-heatmap-layer).